# How to create multiple pages with its own set of widgets in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to be able to create multiple pages each with a set of widgets drop down, radio button and a space to plot a map. The Shiny tutorial shows how to create multiple pages

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("My Application",
  tabPanel("Component 1"),
  tabPanel("Component 2"),
  tabPanel("Component 3")
))
```

How can I add widgets in each page for e.g. how can I  add the following to Component 1?

```
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectizeInput(
            'id', label = "Year", choices =   NULL,multiple=FALSE,selected="X2015",
            options = list(create = TRUE,placeholder = 'Choose the year')

        ),
        # Make a list of checkboxes
        radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
                     choices = list("Choice 1" = 1,
                                   "Choice 2" = 2)
```

and

```
     mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably read the reference page of `tabPanel`: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/tabPanel.html

```
shinyUI(
    navbarPage("My Application",
             tabPanel(
               "Component 1",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   selectizeInput(
                     'id', label="Year", choices=NULL, multiple=F, selected="X2015",
                     options = list(create = TRUE,placeholder = 'Choose the year')
                   ),
                   # Make a list of checkboxes
                   radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
                                choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2)
                   )
                 ),
                 mainPanel( plotOutput("distPlot") )
               )
             ),
             tabPanel("Component 2"),
             tabPanel("Component 3")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do `tabPanel("Component 1", ...)`, replacing the dots with all of your `sidebarPanel` code.  Or, use `renderUI` on the server side,

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        navbarPage("My Application",
                   tabPanel("Component 1", uiOutput('page1')),
                   tabPanel("Component 2"),
                   tabPanel("Component 3")
                   )
    ),
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        output$page1 <- renderUI({
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    selectizeInput(
                        'id', label = "Year", choices =   NULL,multiple=FALSE,selected="X2015",
                        options = list(create = TRUE,placeholder = 'Choose the year')
                    ),
                    ## Make a list of checkboxes
                    radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Radio buttons"),
                                 choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2))
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    plotOutput('distPlot')
                )
            )
        })

        output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ plot(1) })
    })
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Never thought of that. I think it would be cleaner to keep the UI in ui.R