# Use pages other than index.html as UI in R Shiny

Tags: html, r, user-interface, shiny

How can I use several HTML pages (including index.html, but others as well) as the web UI using Shiny R? I've gone through the entire reference documentation (http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/) but haven't found a solution.

Comment: you mean how one can make a complete website with shiny and add pages to it?

Comment: Yes, or rather just how to apply Shiny to other pages than index.html.

Comment: Can try this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108018/how-to-create-multiple-pages-with-its-own-set-of-widgets-in-shiny

Comment: or [Radshiny](https://github.com/benjh33/radshiny) . I'm not familiar with it though

Comment: That is an interesting option, I'll look into it. My specific case would require the app to work on different html pages though.

Comment: It sounds like you mean you want to embed shiny in different web pages, is that right?

Comment: @Elin Yes it is